# Displaying User meta in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to display the posts of a user using the following meta function:

```
<?php 
 $user_id = get_current_user_id();
 $key = '';
 $single = true;
 $user_List = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single ); 
 echo '<p>The '. $key . ' value for user id ' . $user_id . ' is: ' . $user_List . '</p>'; 
?>
```

It works fine, when the $key is only one item. I want to use this code to run the same query for multiple keys (as my Key is the post id) so that I can use it to display posts for the that user as follows:

```
<?php
$args = array(
          'post_type' => 'todo_listing',
          'posts_per_page' => 4,
          'order' => 'asc',
          'meta_key' => '1014',
          'meta_query' => array(
              array(
                  'key' => '$id',
                  'meta_value_num' => '1',

                  )
              )
          );
  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

 ?>     

 <?php
 while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
 ?>
 <?php echo get_the_ID();?> <?php the_title(); ?>


 <?php
endwhile;
?>
```

How can i modify this it achieve this?

Comment: Just call `get_user_meta( $user_id );` without specifying the key, you will get meta data for that particular user.

Comment: Thanks but i only want the user data with posts of that user and not all the data

Comment: Than what is key for that ?

Comment: As i want to use this Key (which is the post id) to show all the posts for the user that have a specific meta key value

Comment: you mean you want all the posts of specific user? Right?

Comment: @jogesh_pi yes but only those posts that meet a certain criteria. Please see my updated question

Comment: Just a thought here, `get_user_meta` have 3 parameters, the third one been `$single`.  When set to true, as in your case, only a single value is returned. If set to false, or just left out (default is false), an array is returned, as opposed to a single value.